# R programming , split time series date

Tags: r

I just have a data file with one column of time series:

```
'2012-02-01 17:42:44'                       
'2012-02-01 17:42:44'          
'2012-02-01 17:42:44'
```

`data.frame(table(cut(MyDates, breaks = c("week", "hours")))`

After converting the the column to as.POSIXct , i'm trying to create a frequency table by weeks and hours of a day
This code does not work.

Please suggest?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, maybe it does work by doing nothing. The viewable data is the

Comment: After converting the the column to as.POSIXct , i'm trying to create a frequency table by weeks and hours of a day

Answer (score 2):

The right argument to use is `breaks = "hour"` (check `?cut.POSIXt`)

```
MyDates<-read.table(text= "2012-02-01 17:42:44
                            2012-02-01 17:42:44         
                            2012-02-01 17:42:44",
                    header = F, sep = "_", 
                    col.names = "date")

# convet to class POSIXct
MyDates <- as.POSIXct(MyDates$date)

# your frequency tables
hours <- table(cut(MyDates, breaks = "hour"))
weeks <- table(cut(MyDates, breaks = "week"))
```